# Is it possible to apply Vue.js to ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

Hello maybe someone of you can help me. Its quite a complicated project which I am working on and I do not even know if it is possible what I am trying to achieve.

What I am trying to do is sending an Ajax request to the server which fetches some files written in vue.js. If I display the response the vue.js components are not rendered again. Is there any possibility to apply vue.js to an ajax response?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I am trying to add a gantt chart inside a wordpress page. The page overall does not use vue.js. Just the gantt chart needs it. If I do not load it with ajax and just load it on page load everything works fine. But I need to load the chart with ajax.

Comment: What do you mean by "some files written in vue.js"? *.vue? *.js? I think you should rethink your design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js - load component from ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546333/vue-js-load-component-from-ajax-call)